# how do i override imbedded function/definition values in python

Tags: python

I apologize in advance if the terminology in my question is incorrect. I want to find out if it's possible to override a variable that is hidden deep in a bunch of consecutive Class calls that you don't have direct access too, but would still effect the outcome.

Here is an example I've tried to write that will hopefully make my question more clear.

I have 3 python modules, test1.py, test2.py and test3.py. Each module has a class and some definitions. Test2.py is where the code is run from.

Test1.py

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, value=5):
        self.a = value
    def foo(self, value3 = 7, value4 = 5):
        from test3 import D
        c = self.a + value3 + value4
        d = D()
        e = d.B()
        f = c + e
        return f

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, value = 1):
        self.d = value
        object1 = A(self.d)
        self.fooReturn = object1.foo()
    def bar(self, value2 = 3):
        f = value2
        g = self.fooReturn + self.d + f
        return g
```

Test3.py

```
class D(object):
    def __init__(self, value=6, wanted_value=9):
        self.value = value + wanted_value
    def A(self, value3 = 4):
        self.value3 = value3 * 2
        return self.value3
    def B(self, value4 = 5):
        valuex = self.A()
        value5 = value4 + self.value + valuex
        return value5
```

Test2.py

```
from test1 import B

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = B(4)
    result = test.bar()
    print result
```

Returns a value of:-

```
55
```

I'm sorry it looks so convoluted, it's my way of trying to make a value look out of normal reach :)

Basically what I would like to do is find out how to redefine the value of 'wanted_value' in the Test3.py, class D, **init** def, while not changing the 'if' in Test2.py.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = B(4)
    result = test.bar()
    print result
```

One way I can see might be possible would be to redefine the class D definition in Test2.py and redirect any call to the original class D to the modified one using a global variable.

e.g.

Test2.py

```
from test1 import B
from test3 import D

class Dx(D):
    # add the value I want to use to 'wanted_value'
    def __init__(self, value=6, wanted_value=3):
        self.value = value + wanted_value

# create a global
D.__init__ = Dx.__init__

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = B(4)
    result = test.bar()
    print result
```

This errors saying 'unbound method_*init*_() must be called with Dx instance as first arguement.

So it's obviously incorrect, but if these is a way to make it work with out having to redefine the whole of class D?

Any help would be great. It may be obvious that my knowledge of inheritance is not too crash hot :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the *inability* to do this is regarded as a feature. The whole point of separating out concerns into different modules/classes is to decouple the implementations, so that small changes to one part of the code don't have flow on effects to break other things everywhere else.

Your `Test2.py` only uses the class `B`. In an ideal world, it shouldn't have to care about the implementation of that class. If `B` is implemented in such a way that its dependence on `D` is not part of `B`'s interface (i.e. there are no parameters or return values of type `D`, nor does it take any parameters to let the user of `B` control the initialisation of `D`), then your code that uses `B` shouldn't be dependent on the fact that `B` uses `D` internally. Tweaking the behaviour you get from `B` by altering `D` couples you to this particular implementation of `B`, and as a side effect will break any other uses of `D` that expect `wanted_value` to have the usual default.

Doing this at module scope is particularly evil, because other unrelated modules that also use `D` will be affected by your changes to class `D`, or not, depending on whether your module has been imported yet, which could happen in completely unrelated parts of the program.

---

So those were all the reasons why you shouldn't normally do this. Presuming you've thought about that and whether there are alternative ways to get what you want and decided it really is what you want, here's how you do it anyway. :)

You were actually on a right track. The trouble is you defined an `__init__` on a class `Dx`, then tried to transfer it to `D`. But when you do `Dx.__init__` you don't get the function object, you get an "unbound method" (in Python 2.x; this concept is gone from Python 3). An "unbound method" is almost exactly like a function, but it checks that its first parameter (usually `self`) is actually an instance of the class you retrieved it from. Since `D`'s `__init__` method is going to be invoked on instances of `D`, not instances of the class you retrieved `Dx.__init__` from (`Dx`), this isn't going to work.

But there's no need to put it in a class. You could just `def __init__`, then assign `D.__init__ = __init__`.

Another way to go about this, if this is just a matter of changing a default parameter of a method is to get at the defaults directly. Here's an example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, apple='orange'):
        self.apple = apple

f = Foo()
print f.apple     # orange

Foo.__init__.im_func.func_defaults = ('octopus',)
f = Foo()
print f.apple     # octopus
```

Whichever way you go about this though, it would be better to do your global hack to `D` just before you create your special `B`, and restore it just after. Probably you should wrap it up in a function:

```
def specialB():
    # save original value of __init__ or func_defaults
    try:
        # hack for D goes here
        b = B()
    finally:
        # restore original value of __init__ or func_defaults
    return b
```

Comment: @ben Thank you very much for the detailed explaination Ben. Exactly what I was after and made perfect sense.

Comment: @Ben Just to expand the question a bit. Is it possible to just change a specific variable in a def that isn't __init__. E.g. Say in Class B, def B() there was a variable, self.variable = 8. Would there be a simple way to override that without rewriting out the whole def and changing it in that?

Comment: @user788462 It depends. That's not a variable, it's a statement assigning the value 8 to `self.variable`. If you want to change it to assigning a different value to `self.variable`, then there's no real good way to do that without rewriting the whole function. However, if you don't need it changed *right there*, you just later have an instance of `B` bound to `b` and you need its `variable` attribute, you can just assign `b.variable = 7`. That won't affect anything that's already used `b.variable` though.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to access deep hidden, nested attributes, but it's error prone. You should consider to rethink your model.

As a rule of thumb: If it's hard to explain it's probably the wrong way.

There seems to be no reason for this nested structure, because you just reuse the values stored in the other objects.

It's like you want to exit your car and therefore lowers the glass, to grasp the door handle from outside to open the door, instead to use the inner door handle.

Basically you want to share some Values. If you really want to create special classes for
shared values you could imagine something like this:

```
class CommonValues(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs): self.__dict__ = kwargs
    def value_exists(self, name): return hasattr(self, name)
    def add_value(self, name, value): setattr(self, name, value)
```

For the actual calculation you could create an abstract base-class, with and init-method, which takes the CommonValues-object as an argument:

```
class CalcBase(object):
    def __init__(self, common_values): self.cvalues = common_values
    def calculate(self): pass
```

For the specific calculations you can subclass:

```
class CalcA(CalcBase):
    def calculate(self):        
        return result if self.cvalues.b > 4 else self.cvalues.c

class CalcB(CalcBase):
    def calculate(self, coef):
        if not self.cvalues.value_exists('d'):
           self.cvalues.add_value('d', 4)   
        result = 4*2 + coef * self.cvalues.c * self.cvalues.d
        return result if self.cvalues.b > 4 else self.cvalues.c
```

And the real-world computation would be something like:

```
cv = CommonValues(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)

resulta = CalcA(cv).calculate()
resultb = CalcB(cv).calculate(3)

cv.c = resulta + resultb
resultc = CalcB(cv).calculate(12.5)
```

Instead of:

```
     depends
 >-----------v
 |           |
 A <-- B <-- C
 ^     |
 |     v
 | <-- D
```

Consider:

```
A -->|
B -->|__> F
C -->| 
D -->|
```

Which graph seems easier to understand and less error-prone? ;-)